# Refactoring a mod_rewrite depending if query string exisits

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang_opt\=E  
RewriteRule /lc/courses.asp english-resource [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang_opt\=F  
RewriteRule /lc/courses.asp french-resource  [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule /lc/courses.asp english-resource [R=301,NC,L]
```

A link comes in 3 flavors
/lc/courses.asp
/lc/courses.asp?lang=E
/lc/courses.asp?lang=F

Is there a more elegant way to deal with these 3 variations of a link. I have quite a few of them and 5 line of mod_rewite per seems excessive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since English is the default, you only need to look for French and redirect everything else to English:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang_opt=F
RewriteRule ^/lc/courses\.asp$ french-resource  [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/lc/courses\.asp$ english-resource [R=301,NC,L]
```